# Airflow task duration capture without accessing database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to access the last executed tasks within DAG and their task duration.
One way i know is by querying the backend DB , in my case its MYSQL.

I have tried below query which works.

```
            select task_id,dag_id,start_date,end_date,duration,execution_date from task_instance where  duration is not null and end_date is not null
```

But due to performance issues over DB , i don't want to query the Database.
Is there any way by which i can access the last executed task and their duration.
I need to create the reports based on this information

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to access that information using Airflow context on `on_success_callback` or `on_failure_callback` calls using `context['task_instance'].duration` inside the callback module.